# C++: Code from wikibooks on overloading pointer/reference related operators won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying a piece of example code from wikibooks (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading), but it won't compile in Visual Studio. The code is about overloading address of, reference, and pointer operators (`operator&()`, `operator*()` and `operator->()`):

```
//file example.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class T {
public:
    const void memberFunction() const {
        std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    }
};

// forward declaration
class DullSmartReference;

class DullSmartPointer {
private:
    T *m_ptr;
public:
    DullSmartPointer(T *rhs) : m_ptr(rhs) {};
    DullSmartReference operator*() const {
        return DullSmartReference(*m_ptr);
    }
    T *operator->() const {
        return m_ptr;
    }
};

class DullSmartReference {
private:
    T *m_ptr;
public:
    DullSmartReference (T &rhs) : m_ptr(&rhs) {}
    DullSmartPointer operator&() const { // error C2027: use of undefined type 'DullSmartReference'
        return DullSmartPointer(m_ptr);
    }
    // conversion operator
    operator T() { return *m_ptr; }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DullSmartPointer dsp(new T);
    dsp->memberFunction(); // calls T::memberFunction

    T t;
    DullSmartReference dsr(t);
    dsp = &dsr;
    t = dsr; // calls the conversion operator

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Visual studio always reports Compiler Error C2079. The error message is

```
1>e:\projects\bad\example.cpp(20): error C2027: use of undefined type 'DullSmartReference'
1>          e:\projects\bad\example.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'DullSmartReference'
1>e:\projects\bad\example.cpp(21): error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'T' to 'DullSmartReference'
1>          Source or target has incomplete type
```

How can I fix the errors?  I'm using VS 2010, but I don't think the version matters.  Thanks!

**Update:**
1. I updated the code and complete error message.

Comment: You mean dereference and address-of operators, not pointer and reference.

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: Also, the code at the bottom is meant to go inside a function such as `main`.

Comment: Because you're trying to return a `DullSmartReference` type in `DullSmartReference operator*() const` and there is no definition, just a forward dec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in that example (at least as it is given) is that `DullSmartReference` is being used before it is defined. On the C2079 line, it is trying to construct and return a `DullSmartReference`, which is impossible without its definition. To fix this, that part of the code should read:

```
// forward declaration
class DullSmartReference;

class DullSmartPointer {
private:
    T *m_ptr;
public:
    DullSmartPointer(T *rhs) : m_ptr(rhs) {};
    DullSmartReference operator*() const;   // DullSmartReference not used yet
    T *operator->() const {
        return m_ptr;
    }
};

// DullSmartReference definition goes here

DullSmartReference DullSmartPointer::operator*() const {
    return DullSmartReference(*m_ptr);  // OK; we have the definition by now
}
```

Comment: The problem was that you hadn't understood the error message, not that the code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to return a `DullSmartReference` object in this line:

```
DullSmartReference operator*() const
```

There is no definition, just a forward declaration.

Therefore,

> **C2079**: The specified identifier is an undefined class, structure, or union.